# KVM for non java enabled mobiles

Tags: java-me

friends please guide me how to run my java application on a non java enabled mobile phones.

i want to add a feature to my application that if mobile phone is not java enabled then automatically before installing java application KVM should b installed on the device to run my application.

thanks in advance

please help me

Comment: By "KVM" do you  mean KJava or Java ME, a JVM?

Comment: I think he means under KVM - Kilobyte VM

Comment: @barmaley, thanks. "KVM"is so overloaded from [Keyboard Video Mouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch) switch, to [Kernel Virtual Machine](http://www.linux-kvm.org), and now [Kilobyte Virtual Machinne](http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/what_kvm.xml).